# What is this error refer to , and how to fix it?

Tags: asp.net, xml, publishing

i got this error when i publish website in remote location , its accrues while using pages 
which contain 
  - autocomplete user control 
  - export report to pdf , show report in report viewer

[image: Error]

Comment: What is on column 435? the dashed line ends there and points to the thing the parser doesn't accept.

Comment: Looks like your XML isn't well formed.  What character is at column 435?  Maybe a `<` or some other character that's being recognized as part of the tags?

Comment: I search for this column and didn't find it , So i need a any way to fix this issue

Comment: You don't see anything when you scroll to where the dashed line ends with a "^"? This is probably (as @ataddeini suggested) a problem with character encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after writing export to pdf code in crystal report, i didn't write

```
     Response.End(); line
```

so other requests raise xml parsing error because first pdf export request not closed.

Answer (score 0):

That usually shows if you install IIS after the .NET.
You need to run aspnet_regiis.exe with the -i option/switch.

For more information, visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/cptools/html/cpgrfaspnetiisregistrationtoolaspnet_regiisexe.asp.

Start > Search > All files and folders > Type aspnet_regiis.exe into search box, and search it under your Windows file (C:\WINDOWS); I found it at C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50215.

Go to DOS command line, change to above directory then execute `aspnet_regiis.exe -i`.

You might need to restart IIS service or your computer.